# Form is submitting multiple entries to the database instead of single

Tags: php, html, mysqli

my code basically override requests (for classes that are full in capacity) submitted by students to specific professors. Let's say 2 students have requested an override to the same class, when a professor is logged in, the code fetches the two override requests with an option of accepting/denying, when i as a professor accept/deny a single override request, it does the action for both the override requests instead of the one i chose.

Basically it's not accepting/denying the requests as selected, its doing the same action for all overrides.

Code:

```
<?php
} else if ($usertype == 1) { 
$server = "";
$user = "";
$pass = "";
$db = "";
$db2 = "";
$db3 = "";
$user1 = $_SESSION['username'];
$mysqli  = new Mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db) or mysqli_error($mysqli);
$mysqli2  = new Mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db2) or mysqli_error($mysqli);
$mysqli3  = new Mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $db3) or mysqli_error($mysqli);

$status= $mysqli->query("SELECT status FROM Overrides WHERE professor = '$user1'")->fetch_object()->status;  
$overrides = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM Overrides WHERE professor = '$user1'"); 
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($overrides);
?>
            <form method="post" action="dbheads.php" name="HF" id="HF" autocomplete="off">
            <script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('HF').action = action;
        document.getElementById('HF').submit();
    }
</script>
<?php if ($status == 1) {

echo "&nbsp;Overrides today: " . $num_rows; 
?>
    <?php
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($overrides)) { ?>
    <fieldset>  <?php
         echo "First Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['name'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Mid. Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['mname'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Fam. Name:&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['fname'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Student ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" . $row['sid'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Scolarship:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['sc'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Phone No:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['phone'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['email'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Subject:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['subject'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Section:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['section'] . "<br />";
         echo "<br />Semester:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; " . $row['semester'] . "<br />"; 

             $name = $row['name'];
             echo "<input type='hidden' name='name' value='$name'>";
         $mname = $row['mname'];
         echo "<input type='hidden' name='mname' value='$mname'>";
         $fname = $row['fname'];
         echo "<input type='hidden' name='fname' value='$fname'>";
         $sid = $row['sid'];
         echo "<input type='hidden' name='sid' value='$sid'>";
         $sc = $row['sc'];
         echo "<input type='hidden' name='sc' value='$sc'>";
         $phone = $row['phone'];
         echo "<input type='hidden' name='phone' value='$phone'>";
         $email = $row['email'];                
          echo "<input type='hidden' name='email' value='$email'>";
         $subject = $row['subject'];
                  echo "<input type='hidden' name='subject' value='$subject'>";
         $section = $row['section'];
                  echo "<input type='hidden' name='section' value='$section'>";
         $semester = $row['semester'];
                  echo "<input type='hidden' name='semester' value='$semester'>";

         ?>
<br />
<div>
<label for="comments" accesskey="c">Notes & Comments:</label><br />
<input type="textarea" name="comments" id="comments" cols="35" rows="10">
<br>
</div>
<br>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm(action)
    {
        document.getElementById('HF').action = action;
        document.getElementById('HF').submit();
    }
</script>

...

<input type="button" onclick="submitForm('dbheads.php')" value="Accept" />
<input type="button" onclick="submitForm('dbheads2.php')" value="Deny" /></form>

    </fieldset>
    <br>
<?php     } }
?>
<br />
```

dbheads.php

```
<?php 
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start();
?>
<html>

    <?php
    $mysql_host     = "";
    $mysql_username = "";
    $mysql_password = "r!~";
    $mysql_database = "";
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
      if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
                <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($user); ?>!</p>
                <?php 
    $mysqli  = new Mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database) or die(mysqli_error());
    $status = 2;

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Overrides SET status=? WHERE username='$user'");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $status);
    $stmt->execute();
     echo htmlentities(accepted);
     ?>
             <?php else : ?>
                <p>
                    <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="index.php">login</a>.
                </p>
            <?php endif; ?>

    </html>
```

bheads2.php

```
<html>

<?php
$mysql_host     = "";
$mysql_username = "";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "";
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
  if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
            <p>Welcome <?php echo htmlentities($user); ?>!</p>
            <?php 
$mysqli  = new Mysqli($mysql_host, $mysql_username, $mysql_password, $mysql_database) or die(mysqli_error());
$status = 5;

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Overrides SET status=? WHERE username='$user'");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $status);
$stmt->execute();
 echo htmlentities(denied);
 ?>
         <?php else : ?>
            <p>
                <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.</span> Please <a href="index.php">login</a>.
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>

</html>
```

Any help on how can i fix this? I'm a beginner so ignore the messy code.

Comment: Could you post your code that updates the database when you click accept or deny please

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are updating the database with the following query

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Overrides SET status=? WHERE username='$user'")
```

Which is simply saying where the username is the person logged in or using the page will be updated to the status of your choosing, do you have a unique identifier for each row of overrides? Override_ID maybe.

If so I would fetch that data on your first page and put it into a hidden input like the other data and then use the following query:

```
$ovid = $_POST['ovid'];
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE Overrides SET status=? WHERE override_id='$ovid'")
```

**EDIT:**

You also seem to be updating `WHERE username='$user'`as opposed to `WHERE professor='$user'` on your update pages

Comment: my unique identifier im using currently is the username logged in. I just want it to update one submittion a time, but currently when i accept/deny an override, it would accept/deny all the overrides i got.

Comment: It can only do one at a time if there is a Unique field in the database, best practice is to have this field as a primary key and auto increment so that it is always unique. Could you post your db structure?

Comment: Not sure if it is relevant but on the update pages you are using `WHERE username='$user'`, shouldnt this be `WHERE professor='$user'` like your original statement?

Comment: Dont do this. This allows the client to determine what id row will be fetched (they can just change the input). Use session storage or something that the user can't modify unless you simply Dont care who sets who's status.

Comment: @Jhawins They can't change the input if it is hidden, they can only see the ID

Comment: @polaris you can change a hidden input... Securitaw